# Scrollable vertical menu jumps to top after clicking on a link

Tags: html, css, django, menu, bootstrap-4

Good evening community,

I have a problem related to a vertical menu that is scrollable when there are more items in the menu than the page can take vertically. If I scroll down to an item that is not displayed on the screen when I'm at the top of the menu and I click this item to get to the respective page, the page will get loaded but the menu jumps back to the top, so that the item i just clicked is not displayed on the screen again. But I want that the part of the menu with the item is shown when the new page is loaded and not the top of the menu.

I'm developing my site with python and django and using bootstrap for frontend, if that helps with my problem.

I will add some pictures to visualize my problem. Sadly i can't post pictures directly yet.

[Starting Position 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHC6M.png) <- This is the top of the menu with the page 'Einführung' loaded

[Scrolled Position 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0wWt.png) <- This is the scrolled position and I want to click the 'Print-Funktion'-link

[Top Position 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2piEt.png) <- This is the menu after I clicked on the link (top position)

[Scrolled Position 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBMvE.png) <- This is the menu when I scroll down after I clicked on the link

I numbered the pictures for easier reference. Currently the menu is in the state of the 3rd picture after I clicked on the link but I want the menu to be in the state of the 4th picture.

Edit1:
I forgot to add how I made the menu scrollable. I used the malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin. [The Plugin](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin)

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution which is not perfect, because it will always jump to the top for some milliseconds after clicking on a link and then to the desired position.

I've used this when the page is loading

```
$(selector).mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",position);
```